# "Any value" for a `const std::string&` argument

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a function that takes `const std::string &` as an argument. I'd like to write something like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, convertString(A<std::string>())).Times(0);
```

This fails compilation:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from 'testing::Matcher<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'const testing::Matcher<const std::basic_string<char>&>&'
```

Am I missing something?

Here is the MCVE, for those inclined to experimment:

```
#include <string>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>


struct ToBeMocked {
    virtual ~ToBeMocked() = default;
    virtual void callMe(const std::string &arg) = 0;
};

struct Mock : public ToBeMocked {
    MOCK_METHOD1(callMe, void (const std::string &arg));
};


    TEST(Test, test)
{
    Mock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, callMe(::testing::An<std::string>()));
    mock.callMe("aaa");
}
```

P.S. I am aware of the StrictMock workaround, and will use it. But... `A<T>()` not working with const ref arguments seems like an oversight...

Comment: @NathanOliver - Shouldn't be a destructive edit. The namespace difference is due to [this](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslstl/bslstl_string.h). But that is supposed to be a standard compliant implementation of the standard library. I just made the post more approachable to the layman.

Comment: @StoryTeller  Yes, you caught me :) I am using https://bde.bloomberg.com/bde-docs/index.html . But that really should not affect the outcome, should it? Unless GMock has some special support for `const std::string &` that other classes do not enjoy.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I suppose one can check it be creating a short example and trying both string versions, but I have no idea how a [mcve] for that will look ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @StoryTeller Right, those MCVEs are a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turns out to be simple:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, callMe(::testing::An<const std::string &>()));
```

Use the EXACT type of the function argument, not the value type.